# Python Django request.GET.get method for urls with if statements

Tags: python, django

I'd like to filter the posts by its two different categories which are schools and category.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'school'
        verbose_name_plural = 'schools'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class VideoPost(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.ForeignKey('School', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def _get_unique_slug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(VideoPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

`School` and `Category` are the foreignKeys for `VideoPost`. So, in the db it would only have its ids, not the slug or name. Which are `category_id & school_id`

views.py

```
def post_list(request):
    school = request.GET.get('school', None)
    category = request.GET.get('category', None)

    posts = VideoPost.objects.all()

    if school:
        posts.filter(school=school).order_by('-date_posted')

    elif category:
        posts.filter(category=category).order_by('-date_posted')

    elif school & category:
         posts.filter(school=school).filter(category=category).order_by('-date_posted')
    else:
        posts.order_by('-date_posted')

## I wanted to filter them in multiple ways where the posts are filtered by either one of the category, or both, but It doesn't work.
## The only way I found that's working is:

   posts = VideoPost.objects.all().filter(school=school).filter(category=category)
##This way, it filtered the posts with its school and category id specified.

    return render(request, 'stories/browse.html', {'posts': posts})
```

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'post_list' %}?school=1&category=4">Link</a>
```

So, my questions are

1. Would it be possible to have text in the db for foreign key? So that url can be more readable, and I could use text in url tag.
   like `<a href="{%url 'post_list' %}?school=MIT&category=sports">Link</a>`
2. How could I use request.GET.get() method with IF statement properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can filter the `VideoPost` by school slug and category slug, you don't need to make the slug field primary key, usually this is a bad design. What you can do is to make the **slug** field **unique**, so you know there is no entries with the same `slug`.
2. Remember that every filter apply to a QuerySet will return a new QuerySet, so you can create a chain of QuerySet.

The following code should work as expected

```
school_slug = request.query_params.get('school', None)
category_slug = request.query_params.get('category', None)   

posts = VideoPost.objects.all()

if school:
    # If we have school, filter by school slug
    posts = posts.filter(school__slug=school_slug)
if category:
    # If we have category, filter by category slug
    posts = posts.filter(category__slug=category_slug)

# Always order the posts by date_posted
posts = posts.order_by('-date_posted')

return render(request, 'stories/browse.html', {'posts': posts})
```

If both `school` and `category` are passed then we apply 2 filter to the queryset

Also, in the future I'll suggest to use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for this use cases.